# How do I figure out which C adapter I need to use a CX4 Microscope Camera?

Tags: lens, adapter, microscopy

I work on very small electronics and I was trying to get a camera to take pictures of the boards that I work on. I ordered a CX4 cmos camera and got a C adapter to attach it to my microscope. It attaches at the top part of the microscope, separate from the eyepieces. The eyepieces are 10X, and are labeled WF10X/20 lenses. But the CX4 camera and the eyepieces are unsynchronized somehow. The camera doesn't display what the eyepieces see.

I've done digging on this site and I know that the C adapter lens has something to do with the difference. The one I have is 0.5X. What kind of C adapter should I get to make things line up correctly? How can I tell?

Edit: Here are pictures of my current setup
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Could you show a drawing or picture of your setup? If you're using the C-mount adapter with a trinocular microscope, you must have eyepiece (ocular) lenses that correspond to the adapter's magnification. Some adapters allow removal of the negative lens, which might help.

Comment: Added some pics for reference.

I checked out the adapter, but unfortunately I don't think I can remove the negative lens.